# SerialPort byte array always returning 0x63 on byte[5]?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a program where I have data coming in through the serialPort, I convert this data into a byte array and then interrogate each byte. However, there are for example 6 bytes (byte[0] to byte[5]) which all mean various things. But for some reason the last byte (byte[5]) always returns a 0x63 in the program, even through the data coming into the port says something different. I have checked the data coming in with a scope to confirm the issues. Below is the relevant part of the code:

```
        SerialPort mySerialport = new SerialPort("COM3",9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        rxString = mySerialPort.ReadExisting();
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rxString);
        textbox1.Clear();

        if (bytes[0] == 0x12)                          //Header
        {
            if (bytes[1] == 0xA6)                      //Header
            {
                if (bytes[2] == address)               //Address
                {
                    byte A = bytes[3];
                    byte B = bytes[4];
                    var checksum = ((address + A + B) ^ 0xFF) & 0xFF;

                    if (checksum == bytes[5])
                    {
                        textbox1.AppendText("Connected OK!!!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        textbox1.AppendText("Byte 5 = " + bytes[5]);
                    }

                }
            }
          }
```

And what I notice, if I display my calculated Checksum in the textbox it is the same as the checksum on the scope (in Byte [5]). So it has to be in the code somewhere that the byte [5] is changing to 0x63.

Thanks, your help is appreciated...

Comment: Your code doesn't seem complete - for example, you don't show you you define `mySerialPort` while you open `port` and never use it. Also you are missing some closing brackets. It is usually easier to help you if you show complete code printouts.

Comment: Sorry, I took loads out that I felt irrelevant...

Comment: 63 is a magic number, unlike 0x63, it is the ASCII code for `?`.  Generated by the ASCIIEncoding class when it has to convert a byte value >= 0x80.  It is the default for the SerialPort.Encoding property.  Never use ReadExisting() to read binary data, use the Read() method instead.  Don't ignore its return value.

Comment: Hello Hans, you mentioned this earlier... I should have spent more time getting the Read() parameter to work in place of the ReadExisting(). Now that I got it working the code works great... Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that the problem is what @Hans Passant referred to - if you want to read binary data (i.e. bytes without caring about how they are encoded as text strings), you shouldn't use the `String` reading methods of `SerialPort`.

You should use [`Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143549(v=vs.110).aspx) to get your bytes directly into a byte array. The code might look like this:

```
 SerialPort mySerialport = new SerialPort("COM3",9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
 byte[] bytes = new byte[10];
 int read = mySerialport.Read(bytes, 0, 10);
```

Its usually a good idea to allocate an array somewhat larger than what you expect to receive, and then refer to the `read` value to understand how many of the bytes in the array actually contain real data.

On the other hand, if you know that your serial device always generates fixed sized data packets (for example maybe 5, in your case?) then you can just allocate a byte array of the size that you need and make sure you've read a full packet every time - possibly repeating the read if you didn't get the full packet:

```
int read = 0;
while (read < packet_size) {
    read += mySerialport.Read(bytes, read, bytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: Hey Guss, thanks. I managed to get it working using the Read(). Seems to be going well, thanks...

Comment: @Graham, if the answer works for you, please approve it. Thanks :-)